# Transparency Issues in Illustrator - Vector Image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, white-space

So I created what I thought was a vector image in Illustrator. I'm completely new to this and still learning how to use the program. Whenever I save it as an EPS, there's white space around the image. I think it has something to do with the blue box around the image, but I can't get just the text and image to save. There's always white space.

Here's what it looks like in Illustrator:

[image]

Another image:

[image]

If you need the file, I can share that, too.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that a collection of vector shapes or a **placed** raster image? It appears to be a raster image. In which case, there's no benefit to using Illustrator. Use Photoshop for raster images. Merely saving something as an .eps file *does not* make it vector.

Comment: I'm trying to make it a logo. It's not a raster image; it was created in Illustrator with text and an icon that I traced. However, I can't figure out what happened that it's gotten this way, unless it was the way that I originally saved it or manipulated the tracing.

Comment: Hard to say. You expended the tracing, though right?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saving the whitespace outside of the graphic to the file.

I think you'll want to either scale the vector up to take up the maximum allowable space of the artboard, or resize the artboard to fit the vector.

You can do this by visiting: File >> Document Setup >> Edit Artboards

#### File >> Document Setup

[image: File >> Document Setup]

#### Edit Artboards

[image: Edit Artboard is in the top-right of the Document Setup dialogue]

#### Scale the artboard to match the proportions of the graphic you're working with

[image: Scale the Artboards]

> These screenshots were taken on a Mac, but it should be a similar process on other operating systems.

Alternatively, you might be able to transform the vector using the scale tool or free-transforming it to fit closer to the bounds of the artboard/stage